# Installing radrails/ruby for the first time - setup is not working

Tags: ruby, radrails

I'm completely new to ruby / radrails.

I've installed radrails and ruby using rubyinstaller (Ruby 1.9.2-p180) and followed the [Configuring your RadRails setup](http://docs.aptana.com/docs/index.php/Configuring_your_RadRails_setup) and when I follow the step to check to see if it was successful (i.e. going to Interactive Ruby) I don't see what the screenshot shows, instead I get the following:

```
internal:lib/rubygems/customrequire:29:in require': no such file to load -- fastri/util (LoadError) from internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require:29:inrequire'
from C:/Users/Ben/My Documents/Aptana RadRails Workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.rubypeople.rdt.launching/ruby/fri:7:in `'
```

Any help would be very much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

RadRails 2.x was created before Ruby 1.9 or Rails 3 were released (by some margin) and is now deprecated. I strongly suggest you migrate to Studio 3 which includes Ruby/Rails functionality and works with Ruby 1.8/1.9 and Rails 2/3.